Rsyslog Client hello message showing Too many ciphers when used tls connection?
I have configured rsyslog over tls , My client hello message sending too many ciphers :
Tried using debian machines and Redhat 8 Machines both resulted in same way.
rsyslog version : 8.2404
gnutls - 3.7.1
SERVER CONFIG :

$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/server-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/server-key.pem

$ModLoad imtcp  
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1  
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode anon
$InputTCPServerRun 6514  


CLIENT CONFIG:
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/pki/tls/private/client-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/client-key.pem
$DefaultNetStreamDriver gtls

$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1   
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon

*.*     @@<ip>:6514

--- Exposing 31 cipher suites , even when many config changes done.
--- Please provide any easiest way or any way to limit those ciphers to desired numbers .
Below is the image showing cipher suites list of client hello message 
